# Conduit: Extracting consequent numbers

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm playing around with conduit library, and have written a sample piece of code for extracting two numbers (2 & 3) when they appear in a sequence. Following is my code:

```
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

source = CL.sourceList [1,2,3,4,5,2,3] :: Source IO Int

-- Extract the consequent 2 and 3 number
extract23 :: Conduit Int IO Int
extract23 = do
  a <- await
  b <- await
  case (a,b) of
    (Just a,Just b) ->
      if a == 2 && b == 3
      then do yield a
              yield b
              extract23
      else extract23
    _ -> return ()

conduit1 :: Conduit Int IO String
conduit1 = CL.map show

sink1 :: Sink String IO ()
sink1 = CL.mapM_ putStrLn

main :: IO ()
main = source $= (extract23 =$= conduit1) $$ sink1
```

But when I execute the `main` function, I get no output. What I expect actually is something like this:

```
2
3
2
3
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code calls `await` twice in a row. What that says is "give me the next two values in the stream, and do not put them back in the stream." When you do this repeatedly, you are essentially breaking your stream into 2-value chunks. Using your original list, you are basically getting tuples that look like:

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,2)] -- final 3 is lost since it has no pair
```

The issue is that you 2,3 sequences always fall *between* two of these tuples. It seems to me like the algorithm you really want is:

- Check if the first two values in the stream match 2,3.
- Proceed forward in the stream by *one* element and repeat.

Currently, you're stepping forward *two* elements in the stream.

Fortunately, there's an easy solution to this problem: instead of using `await` to get the second value, which removes it from the stream at the same time, use `peek`, which will look at the value and put it back. If you replace `b <- await` with `b <- CL.peek`, you should get the behavior you're looking for.

**UPDATE**

Just to give a little bit more information. Under the surface, `peek` is implemented on top of two primitives in conduit: `await` and `leftover`, like so:

```
peek = do
    mx <- await
    case mx of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just x -> do
            leftover x
            return (Just x)
```

There's nothing magical about this ability to look ahead by 1 element. You can similarly look ahead 2 elements. The only trick is making sure to do the leftovers in the correct order:

```
peek2 = do
    mx <- await
    my <- await
    maybe (return ()) leftover my
    maybe (return ()) leftover mx
    return (mx, my)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. But what if I wanted to see the third element also in the stream ? How to handle in that case ? `peek` doesn't seem to work in that case.